# generate list of functions at top of module page in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I feel like this should be simple but after hours of experimenting/searching, I'm nowhere.

I have a module `foo.py` in a package called `mypackage`:

```py
def foo1(bar1, bar2):
    """foo some bars

    Parameters
    ----------
    bar1 : bar
        A bar to foo.
    bar2 : bar
        Another bar to foo.
    """
    pass

def foo2(bar1, bar2):
    """foo some bars a different way

    Parameters
    ----------
    bar1 : bar
        A bar to foo.
    bar2 : bar
        Another bar to foo.
    """
    pass
```

And a `foo.rst` file:

```
``foo`` Module
==============

.. automodule:: mypackage.foo
    :members:
```

After `make html`, I get a listing of all functions with their call signatures and docstrings -- which I want:

[image]

**But I also want an auto-generated list of all of the functions,** at the top of the page, preferably with hyperlinks to the functions lower on the page. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.  The workflow is unintuitive and there are multiple ways to get similar (but subtly different) results.

Try the [sphinx.ext.autosummary](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html) extension.  It creates a table of single-line summaries.  If you put this in the package's `__init__.py` docstring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""This is top-level docstring in __init__.py.

.. autosummary::

    mypackage
    mypackage.foo
    mypackage.foo.foo1
    mypackage.foo.foo2
"""
```

it renders as (HTML, `bizstyle` theme):

[image: render1]

Or expand on that using the [sphinx-autogen](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-autogen.html) script to generate stub documents.  It groups members by `Functions` and `Classes`.  So, (step #1) put this in the `index.rst` document (note addition of `:toctree:` option):

```
.. autosummary::
    :toctree: stubs_autogen

    mypackage
    mypackage.foo
    mypackage.foo.foo1
    mypackage.foo.foo2
```

Then (step #2) `make html` now generates stub documents (assuming [autosummary_generate](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#confval-autosummary_generate) flag in `conf.py` is enabled), which renders as:

[image: render2]

Side note: I find the `sphinx-autogen` script painful... and avoid it.  It doesn't play friendly with [sphinx.ext.autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) extension ("use `:noindex:` for one of them" warnings) or honour the Sphinx `conf.py` file (you fiddle the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable).

By the way, your `foo.rst` looks handcrafted.  Did you use the [sphinx-apidoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) script to auto-generate stub documents?

```
$ sphinx-apidoc --force --module-first -o stubs_apidoc mypackage
```

---

**Addendum #1**

I keep a precious script that I adapt (it's like catching lightning in a bottle). Although any time I must dig inside I hate the schizophasia a little more: apidoc, autodoc, autogen, autosummary.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function setup1(){
    rm -Rf myproject
    sphinx-quickstart \
        --no-sep \
        --project alice --author bob --release 1 --language en \
        --ext-autodoc \
        --extensions sphinx.ext.autosummary \
        myproject  
    # https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-quickstart.html
    mkdir -p myproject/mypackage/
    cp foo.py myproject/mypackage/
    sed -i '1i #!/usr/bin/env python\n"""This is the module docstring."""\n' myproject/mypackage/foo.py

    cat << EOF > myproject/mypackage/__init__.py
"""This is top-level docstring from __init__.py.

.. autosummary::

    mypackage
    mypackage.foo
    mypackage.foo.foo1
    mypackage.foo.foo2
"""
EOF

    sed -i "s|# import os|import os|" myproject/conf.py
    sed -i "s|# import sys|import sys|" myproject/conf.py
    sed -i "s|# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))|sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))|" myproject/conf.py
    sed -i "s|html_theme = 'alabaster'|html_theme = 'bizstyle'|" myproject/conf.py
    printf "\nautosummary_generate = True\n" >> myproject/conf.py  # https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-autogen.html
    sed -i "13i \ \ \ stubs_apidoc/modules\n"  myproject/index.rst
}

function setup2(){
    cat << EOF >> myproject/index.rst



.. autosummary::
    :toctree: stubs_autogen

    mypackage
    mypackage.foo
    mypackage.foo.foo1
    mypackage.foo.foo2
EOF

    export SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS=members,undoc-members,show-inheritance,noindex
    # avoid WARNING: duplicate object description, use :noindex: for one of them
}

function build(){
    cd myproject
    sphinx-apidoc --force --module-first -o stubs_apidoc mypackage
    # https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html
    make html  # SPHINXOPTS=-q
}

clear
if [ "$1" == "1" ]; then
    setup1
    build
elif [ "$1" == "2" ]; then
    setup1
    setup2
    build
else
    echo 'Error - arg required (1, 2)'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be close to what I want but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. I will keep trying. TBH I can't remember how I generated the `.rst` files. Maybe automatically at first (a while ago) then I made some changes, then I've been copying and pasting from there?

Comment: See addendum (the script I used to make screenshots)